# Global Payments eComm API - Not retrieving ALL TransactionDetail

Tags: global-payments-api

[Someone asked about how to retrieve transaction detail from Global Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345664/how-to-query-past-payments-in-global-payments-api) last year and I know how to do this, but when I make the call to retrieve the transaction detail, I'm not getting ALL the details.

I ran into a situation where several customers paid, and my service was inaccessible due to a URL change. Using the ReportingService.TransactionDetail() method seemed the way to go but it only retrieves *some* of the data. Some critical information is missing from the response:  Amount, TransactionDate, Customer Info...just to name a few.

Why doesn't the **ReportingService.TransactionDetail** respond with **all** of the transaction detail?

[image]
[image]