# How to check if a payment is delayed, pending, or batched in Global Pay using the Ecommerce API?

Tags: c#, .net, global-payments-api

I'm using the Hosted Payment Page (HPP) solution from the Global Pay Ecommerce API to make payments: https://developer.globalpay.com/ecommerce/hosted-solution/HPP-Guide#hpp

Does anyone know how to determine if payments are in the delayed, pending or batched state in Global Pay using the Ecommerce API?

[Example payments in Global Pay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O04a.png)

I've tried using the `ReportingService.TransactionDetail()` method found in the Global Pay .NET SDK tests, but the returned `TransactionSummary` didn't contain the payment state.

Global Pay test code: https://github.com/globalpayments/dotnet-sdk/blob/master/tests/GlobalPayments.Api.Tests/GpEcom/GpEcomReportingTest.cs

My code:

```
var service = new HostedService(new GpEcomConfig 
{ 
    MerchantId = "merchantid", 
    AccountId = "accountid", 
    SharedSecret = "secret", 
    ServiceUrl = https://api.sandbox.realexpayments.com/epage-remote.cgi, 
    HostedPaymentConfig = new HostedPaymentConfig { Version = "2" } 
}); 

var transactionSummary = ReportingService.TransactionDetail("bb80e964-8f0e-4a67-90d9-78a617fde3bb").Execute();
```

Example transaction summary:
[Example transaction summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW4Tz.png)

I can see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090241/global-payments-ecomm-api-not-retrieving-all-transactiondetail), but it doesn't have any answers.